# Interval script is not displaying the time on my page php

Tags: php, time, intervals

Am running a script the executes a script every minute but for some reason it not appearing on my browser, cant tell if its running.

```
<?php


set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
$interval=1; //minutes
echo str_repeat(" ", 1024);
while(true) {
    $now=time();
    echo $now."<BR>";
    sleep($interval * 60);
    flush();
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: try ob_flush() too http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 0):

Because php doesn't work like this. PHP is serversided, it will generate everything and send the HTML to the client. You have to use javascript for this